# Fade out HTML Element / CSS Masking

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to fade out an HTML element. Specifically, I want to fade out a list of messages in a video chat from opaque to transparent in the top. 
All I have found so far are either fades of the whole element or some cheap CSS gradients to color. Either I'm looking for the wrong thing or there simply isn't any good accessible solutions.
I've looked into SVG masking which is exactly what I want but which doesn't seem to work for what I'm trying to achieve.

So how would I best go about this problem?

Comment: A simple overflow is probably not, what you want, right?

Comment: @Geshode unless there's a way to fade that to transparent, no

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>

<p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}    
p {
  max-width: 200px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(245,245,245,0.9);
  padding: 150px 0;
}    
#top {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  height: 300px;
  width: 101%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}    
#bottom {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 101%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/torjescu-sergiu/pen/YOzgZq

Comment: this would be my fallback option but the problem with this is, that it only works if you have a background-color (or maybe even an image). In a video call i need it to fade to transparent instead to a certain color